# How can I scrape an information from Wester Union webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the currency convertion information of https://www.westernunion.com/ (attached photo). I found the corresponding tag but it returns an empty list.

Can anyone help me? I appreciate that.

Here is my current code (using BeautifulSoup):

```py
# Web Crawling:
import requests
# Web Scrapping:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Regular Expressions: 
import re

url = 'https://www.westernunion.com/br/pt/web/send-money/start?ReceiveCountry=AR&ISOCurrency=ARS&SendAmount=100.00&FundsOut=BA&FundsIn=WUPay'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
information = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'ng-star-inserted'})
information
```

Only need that simple information "*1.00 BRL = 0.1596 British Pound*"
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WU loads that bit with javascript, all you're scraping with requests is a loading page full of placeholders
[image: screenshot]

The [POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYIJ2.png) they seem to be using to populate that field looks very difficult to replicate (see [this code](https://gist.github.com/Driftr95/25f57259086fabce6f929974c6f2f7c6) which I copied from [curlconverter](https://curlconverter.com/))

---

You might consider using [selenium](https://medium.com/featurepreneur/an-introduction-to-web-automation-using-selenium-python-2ad84814b11c). I have [a function](https://gist.github.com/Driftr95/cbae6710c134df708f44ade8503f6638) for cases like this; if you copy it to your code, you can simply call it

```py
soup = linkToSoup_selenium(url, tmout='3')
# YOU MIGHT NEED TO ADJUST tmout - it sets the wait time for loading
# (3sec seems to be more that enough for me, but it can vary)

if soup is not None: 
    convSpan = soup.select_one('span#smoExchangeRate')
    if convSpan is not None:
        print(convSpan.get_text(strip=True))

# output:
# 1.00 BRL = 56.5617Argentine Peso(ARS)
```

[Yes, the conversion in the printed line is to Pesos - when I manually open the link in your code, I see the same thing; I believe you have to set set [ReceiveCountry=GB&ISOCurrency=GBP](https://www.westernunion.com/br/pt/web/send-money/start?ReceiveCountry=GB&ISOCurrency=GBP&SendAmount=100.00&FundsOut=BA&FundsIn=WUPay) in the link to get `1.00 BRL = 0.1576British Pound(GBP)` as output.]

Comment: Amazing!! Really amazing!! Thank you for your big help. It worked nicely.